# How to set the "title" in a lookup field

Tags: lookup-column, spfield, jquery-ajax

if you have a lookup field, its Html source is depicted as:

```
<option value="79" title="G0058">G0058</option>
```

I could use jquery to change the title from G0058 to company1 (field name: description) but I wonder if you can do this OOTB.

Thank you

Comment: what is the problem/feature that you are trying to solve here?

Answer (score 0):

I would think the easiest way would be to edit the field settings through the UI and switch the "In this column" select to your Description field of the source list.

The resulting html in this case would be

```
<option value="79" title="company1">company1</option>
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to change only  the  title="G0058", so when the user hovers on the item, it will show the description of the company. I did it with jquery